# How can we use cursor and access database in Service class in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-service, android-cursor

I have an Sqlite database that has a collection of locations. And a continuously running service which runs in background and get location and compare with stored locations available in database.

Currently I am reading data through SQLiteDatabase.query method which returns cursor.
But application is crashing due to this (Already cursor closed error)

My question is How can we access database or use cursor in service? 
What would be the best way to use cursor in service?

I don't know about content provider much. But have doubt that I need to implement ContentProvider for this purpose.

I am stuck here. Please guide me for this.

Thanks in Advance.

**Update**
My code is look like

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Location Updated");

    latitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
    longitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();

    Cursor cursor = mDatabaseManager.getAllLocations();
    // Do something
    cursor.close();
}
```

This method means location change callback is implemented in service class.

Comment: what problem do you have in your `Service` code?

Comment: When I take data from database using cursor, sometimes app is crashing due to exception. (exception due to accessing already closed cursor). Not every time crashing. And I have not closed cursor when I am using it.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: and where does the exception occur?